# Verification of these logical forms

Tags: logic

I came across the following two conditionals on a pre-test, and thought I knew the answers but, as it turns out, I thought wrong. Could someone shed some light on my mistakes?

> If the food chain in the ocean collapses, then large bodied animal life on earth will go extinct. The food chain in the ocean has not collapsed. So, large bodied animal life on earth is not extinct.
> **Correct answer:** – valid, modus ponens
> **My Answer:** – invalid, inverse error

$C = \text{food chain in the ocean collapses}$
$E = \text{large bodied animal life on earth will go extinct}$
$ C \implies E, \neg C $
$ \therefore \neg E $

> If Vitamin C is consumed, then Vitamin C will cure scurvy. Everyone in this village is deficient in vitamin C. So, everyone in this village does not have scurvy.
> **Correct answer:** – invalid, inverse error
> **My Answer:** – ???

$C = \text{Vitamin C is consumed}$
$S = \text{Vitamin C will cure scurvy}$
$ C \implies S, \neg C $
$ \therefore S$

Not sure why the second one is invalid inverse error?

If you're wondering if the second conditional has added/missing words, it doesn't. I copied the question exactly from the pre-test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "correct" answer is not. The second question is so poorly phrased as to make it ambiguous, at best, but no reasonable interpretation makes the "correct" answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first is of the form $A\implies B$, so $\neg A\implies\neg B$.

The second is of the form $A\implies B$, so $\neg A\implies B$.

Both arguments are wrong.